# Why is there an external IP on my home LAN network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, arp

I am detecting an unknown IP address on my home LAN network. Can someone explain to me why might this be?

[image: IP list]

Comment: Does it match your public IP?

Answer (score 2):

The 100.64.0.0/10 (100.64.0.0 – 100.127.255.255) space is set aside for Carrier Grade NAT, as defined in [RFC 6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598). This is likely the external interface of your router. Nothing to worry about.